# Sending an html attachment with ActionMailer 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attachment, actionmailer

I am trying to send an email which contains a single HTML attachment. The problem is that the attachment html is appearing in the body of the email, and the view is showing up as the attachment. Pretty much the opposite of what I expected.

I am able to send attachments of other types properly, but when trying to send a single attachment that is HTML, it consistently is displayed rather than 'attached'.

```
class Notifier < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "from@example.com"

  def welcome(email)
    attachments['this is an html file.html'] = "<b>yeah this is html!</b>"
    mail(:to => email, :subject => "Attempting an attachment")
  end
end
```

And my `app/views/notifier/welcome.html.erb`

```
Hi there! This is <b>html</b> within a view
```

The resulting email looks like this:

(notice the attachment html is actually displayed in the body of the email)
[image: my image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature of many email clients that if they can display attachments inline they will, so the user doesn't have to open a separate program just to see what's inside. To be honest though it's more meant for images.

If you want to send an html file, you're going to need to add it to a zip or other archive and send that instead.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'd still like to know why the attachment is displayed and the view is sent as an HTML attachment with no filename. Something just isn't right. Via this web-based mail client, I am able to attach an html file and it works as expected. I think I am doing something incorrectly with actionmailer.